# getting error in assign array value to variable in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have following function to fetched value from db:

```
$src = getSrc($r['Section']);
```

I want to return 2 variables value from function. So, I have stored it in array,as follow:

```
$src['img'] = $row['img'];
$src['link'] = $r2['link'];
print_r($src);
return $src;
```

Output for `print_r($src);` is:

```
Array ( [img] => images/about_us.jpg [link] => About Us )
```

But when I assigned this value to variable as follow:

```
$src_val = $src['img']."<br>";
$link_val = $src['link'];
```

It gives output as

```
images/about_us.jpg
i
```

I am not able to get value of $link_val. Please explain.

Comment: _“So, I have stored it in array,as follow: `$src = $row['img'].";". $r2 ['link'];`”_ - that’s not an array. And that print_r of that variable generates the ouput you have shown, is also impossible.

Comment: Where is `getSrc()`?

Comment: @ CBroe I edit my question. I am using $src = $row['img'].";". $r2 ['link']; right now to get output anyway. Edited question is correct.

Comment: Please pay better attention when writing your question. Copy/paste code whenever possible instead of re-writing it by hand.  When you change the code in your question, you are fundamentally changing what has been asked, causing confusion, potentially invalidating answers, and wasting people's time.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how did you get that print_r output from, but this

```
$src = $row['img'].";". $r2 ['link'];
```

should be

```
$src = array('img' => $row['img'], 'link' => $r2['link']);
```

### Update

Typo in `$src['link'] = $r2['link'];`?
Should be

```
$src['link'] = $row['link'];
```

Comment: $src['link'] = $r2['link']; is not typo. I am taking value from 2 different array.